Save layer to file or array buffer and trim
I'm trying to export a layer to a file or arraybuffer from Photopea. Photopea supports command actions from Photoshop. I'm looking for the command action. So theoretically the Photoshop action should work. I also need to make sure the layer is trimmed. Some of the examples I've found hide all visible layers except the selected layer and then export the document (leaving large transparent areas around the layer).
This question is different than this related question because the related question is about a script and not action code afaik (plus the answers have links but not the content).
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21552200/save-layer-to-file-and-trim\
I found an open source project that has some code that looks like it has some actions and some script code (that is maybe not actions).
// export document
app.activeDocument.exportDocument(fileName, ExportType.SAVEFORWEB, prefs.formatArgs);
// save as
app.activeDocument.saveAs(fileName, prefs.formatArgs, true, LetterCase.toExtensionType(prefs.letterCase));

Why isn't there an export layer method?
app.activeDocument.exportLayer(); // doesn't exist

